# Is it possible to pass/compare a variable to an SQL database from within a javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database

Basically my code declares a variable which checks to see if a specific string is entered into a textbox, when the user presses enter, then using substring, it declares a variable which contains a string after the specific word entered (shown below).

I would like to pass this variable to php and ultimately compare it against an SQL database or (but i've heard this is insecure/impossible) compare it directly against an SQL database from javascript.

Is this possible?

```
var match = textInput.value.indexOf("string");

if (keycode == 13 && match != -1) { <- checks to see if enter is pressed + "string" has been typed.
    var some_string = text.input.value.substring(7); <- takes everything after the word "string"
```

and this is where I would like to pass the variable 'some_string' to the SQL database, to perform a check and return true or false.

I hope this is clear and thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use an [ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). You should do it asynchronously, otherwise the browser will hang.

But an asynchronous request works with callbacks, and does not return more than maybe a promise. So, instead of

```
function synchronous(){
    // init xhr and send
    return xhr.response; // or json-parse of response-text or something
}
try {
    if (synchronous() == "wanted value")
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
} catch(e) {
    // alert a problem
}
```

you would need to use

```
function asychronous(success, error) {
    // init xhr, register handlers and send
    // return nothing
}
asynchronous(function scb(data) {
    if (data == "wandted value")
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
}, function ecb(e) {
    // alert a problem
});
```

Comment: An ajax introduction (to XmlHttpRequest) is linked. However, I'm sure you will want to use your favorite libraries ajax functions.

Answer (score 2):

Use AJAX to pass the value to a PHP request handler that uses the value in the appropriate database call. For safety, escape the parameter with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp) when building the SQL. Then have the handler return a response to indicate the outcome (JSON/XML/text/...).

Comment: Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to do the ajax calls. It wraps things up quite nicely. Note the examples towards the end of the linked page.

Comment: @four33: It's exactly the same.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: No, it's not. You shouldn't use synchronous ajax, and therefore a function call in an if-condition will never be able to return the desired value.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, you're right. I didn't register that the OP was using the response synchronously.